# How to avoid inserting a duplicate document to Elasticsearch by checking a specific field

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a `hash_file` field in my index, and want to prevent inserting duplicate documents by checking this field.

1. how can I check when inserting data (not before insert)?
2. with bulk function how can I check this?

ps:I use version6.8

Comment: May I ask you what do you want from deduplication? Is it that you simply don't want duplicated items in Elasticsearch, but it is ok to overwrite the document? If so, Soumitra's answer will do. But if you want to actually keep the original document intact and *not* insert a document with same `hash_file`, it is actually different. So which one it is?

Comment: @NikolayVasiliev,good advice ,the second one,i want to actually keep the original document intact and not insert a document with same hash_file(ignore same document)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, please see my comment to soumitra's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not use the hash_file field's value as the document id, so that there are unique documents for each given hash value and you do not need to worry about checking for duplicates. Unless of-course you specifically need the documents to have some type of id that you are going to use later.

If you decide to use the hash value as the _id though keep in mind that
_id is limited to 512 bytes in size and larger values will be rejected.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I second this approach. One can use [parameter `op_type=create`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.5/docs-index_.html#docs-index-api-query-params) to avoid creating duplicate documents when indexing. This can be also easily combined with [bulk API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.5/docs-bulk.html).

Comment: @NikolayVasiliev Thank you for guidance, but I forgot to say that I use v6.8 of elasticSearch.

Comment: @mohammadhossein Should work the same in 6.8, see this [doc page](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/docs-index_.html#operation-type). Also the [bulk API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/docs-bulk.html).

Comment: @NikolayVasiliev oh, I didn't see that.thank you very much